# CSS Flexbox: flex item grow when changing another flex items position

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

In the example below I have 3 flex items. What I want to do is let the green one grow when I change the position of the blue one. I cant find a way to do it in CSS or should I write it manually in JS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnStart").click(function(){
   $("#three").addClass("slide-right");
  });
});
```

```css
main {
 display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
 position: relative;
}

#one {
  width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
}

#two {
  flex: 1;
 background-color: green;
}

#three {
  width: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  
 
  transition: left 400ms;
}

#three.slide-right {
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Start" />
<main>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the position of the `div` is `relative` changing the left property doesn't change the layout.

According to the [MDN article about position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> **relative**
>
> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not
>   positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing
>   layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have
>   been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on
>   table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption
>   elements is undefined.

---

If you don't won't to change the width of the element itself because you want it to slide. You can wrap it in a container, and change the container's width (see code snippet).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnStart").click(function() {
    $("#threeContainer").addClass("slide-right");
  });
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#one {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
#threeContainer {
  width: 200px;
  transition: width 400ms;
}
#threeContainer.slide-right {
  width: 0;
}
#three {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Start" />

<main>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="threeContainer">
    <div id="three">
      I'm an example text that won't change when #three slides
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, element is only moved at screen, initial space it uses do not become avalaible.

You may use a negative margin to free some space and looking like pulling the green element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnStart").click(function(){
   $("#three").addClass("slide-right");
  });
});
```

```css
main {
 display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
 position: relative;
}

#one {
  width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
}

#two {
  flex: 1;
 background-color: green;
}

#three {
  width: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  
 
  transition: left 400ms;
}

#three.slide-right {
  left: 200px;
  margin-left:-200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Start" />
<main>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</main>
```